# can't run c++ file (.cpp) in CLion

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, cmake

I am a level -1 C++ programmer and this is my first program running c++ and I'm trying to run hello world in C++ but when I run ''myfirstprogram.cpp'' after compiling it.

CLion gives error

it can't run the .cpp file because it can't build it for some reason can someone help me?

I already have Xcode installed and command line tools.

in preferences CLion detected Xcode automatically.

gcc, cc and c++ is already correctly installed.

```
mehmetalibayram@MacBook-Pro-van-Mehmet ~> whereis gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
mehmetalibayram@MacBook-Pro-van-Mehmet ~> whereis cc
/usr/bin/cc
mehmetalibayram@MacBook-Pro-van-Mehmet ~> whereis g++
/usr/bin/g++
mehmetalibayram@MacBook-Pro-van-Mehmet ~>
```

```
/Applications/Jetbrains/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build "/Users/mehmetalibayram/OneDrive/CLion/cpp/cmake-build-debug" --target cpp -- -j 12
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable cpp
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/myfirstprogram/myfirstprogram.cpp.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/build.make:119: cpp] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:138: cpp] Error 2
```

what did I do wrong, can someone help me please?

Comment: The error is plainly before your eyes. You are building a program out of two files, `main.cpp` and `myfirstprogram.cpp`. Each one has `main` function.

Comment: why did you not include the listing of your program?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

A function needs to be uniquely identifiable. In our case you have two functions with the same name, `main`, to be specific. Make sure that you have a single `main` function (which will be the entry point, by the way), so rename the other function to something else and call it from your `main`.

Comment: Your error message tells us that your build includes main.cpp and myfirstprogram.cpp. Since it seems that you only need main.cpp at this point, you will need to exclude myfirstprogram.cpp from your build.

Comment: @MehmetBayram I know you are frustrated, but don't worry, you will get into this successfully. It appears that I misunderstood what you needed. You seem to want to use both files. You can do so. But your actual problem is that you have a `main` function in both which creates a paradox. So either stop using one of the files, or rename one of the main functions or do anything which results in not having duplicate function names. That will fix this issue.

Comment: when I click right mouse button I can't see the ''build'' option in C++ where can I build my application ? maybe that's the reason why I can't run it because it is not built.

Comment: @MehmetBayram take a look at the quote you have pasted into your question, particularly the first line: `/Applications/Jetbrains/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build "/Users/mehmetalibayram/OneDrive/CLion/cpp/cmake-build-debug" --target cpp -- -j`. Try running this. We expect the exact same error to occur, but don't worry: the error says that the problem occurs in CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/build.make at line 119. So, open up that file and take a look at its contents. That's the good direction, which brings you closer to the solution.

Comment: The technical problem you have is that you have two instances of the main function, which makes it ambivalent. The real problem, on the other hand is that you are not (yet) comfortable with working with make files. No worries, all of us were in your position and you will make it (pun intended :)) as well.